# comment out an interval in matlab through command line

Tags: matlab

I have a very long script in MATLAB (1500 lines) and want to test two different settings. To do so, I need to comment out some codes in a specific interval (e.g. form line 234 to line 255).

Is there a function in MATLAB that takes the intervals and comments/uncomments them automatically?

Comment: [This link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122-how-do-i-comment-out-a-large-block-of-code-in-matlab) answers your question.

Comment: Write an `if-else` and pass an additional index to the function if necessary. For example, if you want to run first of the three sections of the code, then you pass an index 1. Accordingly write `if-else`. I am not aware of anything that will comment code programmatically. Above comment does not give you an automatic way of commenting codes.

Comment: Yes, I think if-else is a better idea for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can just highlight your code and click on the comment button. Highlight and click on uncomment to remove comment.In windows you may also use shortcut keys cntrl+r and cntrl+t. But yeah, the if else is a better idea but takes more time in the beginning to code in the if else.

Comment: This is not an answer the original question. And it has already been said in the comments.

Comment: Thank you Ratbert and SOfanatic for your clarification. Will add comments from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with others that putting your code into a block surrounded by `if-else` would probably be a better solution than what you originally asked for.

But if you want to do it, you can use the following function:

```
function commentout(fromline, toline)

currentDoc = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;

currentDoc.insertTextAtPositionInLine(sprintf('%%{\n'), fromline, 0)
currentDoc.insertTextAtPositionInLine(sprintf('%%}\n'), toline+1, 0)
```

This will work in most recent versions of MATLAB.

To uncomment, I think you'll need to do something a bit more complex, like getting the entire text from the active document, removing the specified comment lines, then setting the entire text back again (get, modify and set the `Text` property of the document).